Vrock spores question
Do the spores extend from the Vrock's central point to a total 15' radius or do the spores extend from the edge(s) of the Vrock to a 15' radius (meaning a total 40' circumference, i.e. 15' from the left, right, top, and bottom side(s) of the Vrock, adding 10' for the large size of the creature)?
Edit: I agree with you, this question wasn't one I'd thought about but I understand and felt it deserved some consideration.
From D&DB: Spores (Recharge 6). A 15­-foot­-radius cloud of toxic spores extends out from the vrock.
This seems a bit ambiguous because the Vrock is a large creature.  From it's original size it seems to convey a 1.5x size emanation. If it were a normal 5' size, the radius might well be 7.5'.
But if you increase the size of the Vrock to Huge or Gargantuan, the cloud wouldn't increase the way it does with the increased-sized Paladin's aura.
Another question was raised about if the spores emanated from the Vrock's outside edges, does that constitute a doughnut where a diminutive/tiny creature sharing the Vrock's space(s) would basically be immune because the 4 squares of the Vrock's space isn't in the area of effect.
In any case, I appreciate your time and assistance.

Welcome to the stack Hakeashar!  Take the tour when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the help center for more in-depth info about the site.

Highly related: How large is a Globe of Invulnerability cast by a Large creature?

The cloud has a 15 foot radius.
In this case, the trait description tells us exactly the size of the cloud:

A 15­-foot­-radius cloud

Therefore, it doesn’t matter the size of the vrock or where the cloud originated from, it is a 15-foot-radius cloud. If it were 15 feet from each of the edges of the vrock’s 10x10 space, then the area would be larger than a 15-foot-radius cloud.
Compare this to the language of Paladin auras, which originate from the paladin’s entire space:

Starting at 10th level, you and friendly creatures within 10 feet of you can’t be frightened while you are conscious.

Aura of courage does not describe a 10-foot radius aura, instead it covers all area within 10 feet of the Paladin.
